# Can someone tell me what "douchebaggy "means?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrases, word-usage

What does 'Captain douche baggy' mean?

For example "The captain douchebaggy is coming''

Comment: I've actually heard of "douchebag" so "douchebaggy" is actually a new addition to me

Answer (score 5):

"Captain Douchebaggy" is a little bit odd, "Captain Douchebag" would be a more likely term I think and searching for "Captain Douche baggy" via Google brings up only this question, but there are many, many hits for "Captain Douchebag".

DrSmooth at [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Captain%20Douchebag) explains all (in short)

> An assclown that generally speaks as if they know what they are talking about however has no f***ing clue. Different than just the plain assclown by their pure consistancy has earned a rank of captain, yet are not quite the level of an admiral, which requires a lifelong dedication to being a douchebag.

---

Further explanation of the terms that make up *Captain Douchebag*:

A *douche*<sup>[i]</sup> is defined as

> A jet of liquid applied to part of the body for cleansing or medicinal
>   purposes:
>
> A device for washing out the vagina as a contraceptive measure.
>
> *informal , chiefly North American* An obnoxious or contemptible person, typically a man:

---

*douchebag* (or *douche-bag*)<sup>[ii]</sup>

> A small syringe for douching the vagina, especially as a contraceptive
>   measure.
>
> *North American informal* An obnoxious or contemptible person,
>   typically a man.

---

And Oxford Dictionaries also has a definition for *douchbaggery*.<sup>[iii]</sup>

> *North American informal* Obnoxious or contemptible behaviour

---

So with *douchebag* defined why "Captain Douchebag"?

I'm inclined to believe that the "Captain" part comes directly from super-hero usage, like "Captain America" or "Captain Marvel". I can't find a definition in a "standard" dictionary for *Captain* that mentions its use in a humorous fashion meaning "the best, the pinnacle, the ultimate, the exemplar, the top dog...", most definitions are explicitly about being the *Captain of something* like a ship, plane, troop division etc. but OED1 has an obsolete adjective listed as

> Chief, principal, leading, head-.

which fits perfectly because *Captain Douchebag* means *The head douchebag*, *the douchebag who can out-douche all other douchebags*.

One of the most recognisable "Captains" to British people is *Captain Slow*. This is the nickname given to [Top Gear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gear_(2002_TV_series)) presenter [James May](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_May), notorious for driving cars very slowly. On the Wikipedia page for James May it is noted he also has other nicknames based on "Captain" those being

> "Captain Sense of Direction" *(although he has none)*, "Captain OCD", "Captain Maths" and "Captain Idiot".

Other uses of "Captain *something*" can be found.

- "[Captain Obvious](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CaptainObvious)" - his super-power is to be able to state the
  obvious.
- "[Captain Hindsight](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Hindsight)" - lectures people on where they
  went wrong.
- "[Captain Verbose](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/34302/6494)" - uses too many words to answer a simple question.
- a whole host of others can be found searching [Urban Dictionary](https://www.google.com/#q=site:urbandictionary.com+captain) (often not safe for work)

---

<sup>[i] "douche". Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/douche (accessed September 26, 2014).</sup>

<sup>[ii] "douchebag". Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/douchebag (accessed September 26, 2014).</sup>

<sup>[iii] "douchebaggery". Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/douchebaggery (accessed September 26, 2014).</sup>